implementing [PBES2 per pkcs#12]
hello i am having a cluster of related problems
firstly, implementing password based encryption V2 as specified in PKCS#12.

what i suspect most is my password based key derivation function V2 implementation.
For one choice of hash and encryption, PBE with SHA and 40 bit RC2-CBC, i am able to recover the data
and one portion of a pfx file -- the public certificate portion.
the private key data remains unrecoverable, as it is PBE with SHA and 3-KEYTRIPLE DES-CBC.
the 40 bit RC2 key is smaller that the initial PBKDF2 hash buffer.
the 192 bit 3DES-3 key is not, and it is almost assuredly the buffer extension part of the algorithm I
have failed to implement.
From pkcs#12, mechanisms, P.276 onward.
I refer to step 60-C, the construction of B and a large integer arithmetic on the input buffer.
when J is 1 i recover the proper key material. The content decrypts to valid DER (of pubcert) using 40 bit
RC2.
I have tried searching many "PBKDF2" implementation do not properly follow PKCS#12 and will not work.
many refer instead to RFC2898, and may or may not implement it,
i am able to recover the data
and one portion of a pfx file -- the public certificate portion.
the private key data remains unrecoverable, as it is PBE with SHA and 3-KEYTRIPLE DES-CBC.
the 40 bit RC2 key is smaller that the initial PBKDF2 hash buffer.
I have tried searching many "PBKDF2" implementation do not properly follow PKCS#12 and will not work.
many refer instead to RFC2898, and may or may not implement it,
I suspect the issue arises when i need to extend the output length to the key size in the pbkdf2 algorithm.

I was half way through an answer when I saw the tiny C# badge. You might want to put that big letters on the beginning of your question, next time. Or better still: on the title! My suggestion was Python.
